# CouchDB View - Filter by List Field Attribute (doc.objects.[0].attribute)

Tags: couchdb

I need to create a view that lists the values for an attribute of a doc field.

Sample Doc:

```
{
   "_id": "003e5a9742e04ce7a6791aa845405c17",
   "title", "testdoc",
   "samples": [
       {
           "confidence": "high",
           "handle": "joetest"
       }
   ]
}
```

Example using that doc, I want a view that will return the values for "handle"

I found this example with the heading - Get contents of an object with specific attributes e.g. doc.objects.[0].attribute. But when I fill in the attribute name, e.g. "handle" and replace doc.objects with doc.samples, I get no results:

```
Toggle line numbers
// map
function(doc) {
  for (var idx in doc.objects) {
    emit(doc.objects[idx], attribute)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will create an array of key-value-pairs where the key is alway the value of `handle`. Replace `null` with a value you want e.g. `doc.title`. If you want to get the doc attached to every row use the query parameter `?include_docs=true` while requesting the view.

```
// map
function (doc) {
  var samples = doc.samples
  for(var i = 0, sample; sample = samples[i++];) {
    emit(sample.handle, null)
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh. I have misread your example doc. Samples is an array. I will update my answer.

Comment: That's excellent, thank you llabball. Can I use a startkey with this setup or will I need to filter in my python app?

Comment: The list is sorted be the keys. You can request a range with the query params `?startkey="..."&endkey="..."`

Comment: Awesome, thanks again llabball.  In truth I'm using the results of this view as a base to find matches across records that have the same handle value in their sample lists.  If there's a possibility of doing that in a view rather than in code, I can create another question and post the link.

Comment: Yes, its possible to use a `reduce` step. Create a new question.

Comment: Posted the follow up. I'm open to alternative suggestions. Just looking to improve performance over iterating through a lot of potential records in code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635502/couchdb-view-find-records-with-matching-value-in-list-field

Answer (score 2):

Like this ->

```
function(doc) { 
    for (var i in doc.samples) {
      emit(doc._id, doc.samples[i].handle)
    }   
}
```

It will produce a result based on the doc._id field as the key. Or, if you want your key to be based on the .handle field you reverse the parameters in `emit` so you can search by `startKey=`, `endKey=`.

Comment: ^5 We ended with almost the same answer :-)

Comment: Thanks sebster. I would accept both but I can't. I upvoted both instead.

Comment: Heh, yeah... well, it's not like we had to many ways to go about this. Actually wait, we had... with all the for types in javascript

Comment: @Jon Reid Thanks, but he was faster so his answer should be accepted anyway. Upvoting his answer as well.

Comment: This is how SO should be, mate :)